# Download the VHD after running sysprep on Azure in DevTest labs

Tags: azure, azure-devtest-labs

I ran sysprep artifact on my VM in DevTest lab using `az lab vm apply-artifacts`
 command.

After that, when I run `az lab vm show`, I get back a computeId, which contains the resource id

compute ID looks like : `"computeId": "/subscriptions/#####/resourceGroups/###/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/####"`.

How do I get the disk path from this. I am more interested in the SAS key, which I can use in AzCopy to download the vhd file associated with this VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, Azure does not support use Azcopy to download the VHD from devtest lab.

As a workaround, we can **create custom image** from this VM (create a snapshot), then use PowerShell to copy this snapshot to another storage account via Azure PowerShell.
[image]

Then we can use this PowerShell to copy this snapshot, Here are the script:

```
#Provide the subscription Id of the subscription where snapshot is created
$subscriptionId = "yourSubscriptionId"

#Provide the name of your resource group where snapshot is created
$resourceGroupName ="yourResourceGroupName"

#Provide the snapshot name 
$snapshotName = "yourSnapshotName"

#Provide Shared Access Signature (SAS) expiry duration in seconds e.g. 3600.
#Know more about SAS here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1
$sasExpiryDuration = "3600"

#Provide storage account name where you want to copy the snapshot. 
$storageAccountName = "yourstorageaccountName"

#Name of the storage container where the downloaded snapshot will be stored
$storageContainerName = "yourstoragecontainername"

#Provide the key of the storage account where you want to copy snapshot. 
$storageAccountKey = 'yourStorageAccountKey'

#Provide the name of the VHD file to which snapshot will be copied.
$destinationVHDFileName = "yourvhdfilename"


# Set the context to the subscription Id where Snapshot is created
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId

#Get the snapshot using name and resource group
$snapshot = Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -SnapshotName $SnapshotName 

#Generate the SAS for the snapshot 
$sas = Grant-AzureRmSnapshotAccess -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -SnapshotName $SnapshotName  -DurationInSecond $sasExpiryDuration -Access Read 

#Create the context for the storage account which will be used to copy snapshot to the storage account 
$destinationContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey  

#Copy the snapshot to the storage account 
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer $storageContainerName -DestContext $destinationContext -DestBlob $destinationVHDFileName
```

More information about this script, please refer to this [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/managed-disks-powershell-getting-started/blob/master/CopySnapshotToStorageAccount.ps1).

---

**Update:**

We can via Azure portal to create image, like this:

[image]

Comment: I am still not sure how creating a custom image (az lab vm custom-image) will create a snapshot. Aren't they different?

Comment: @PranavRaj we also can use portal to create image, I will update my answer, please check it.